# SQL Server - Subquery in Join vs Subquery in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I have a situation where I have source tables that get dumped with all the historic data on a daily basis. The way for me to extract the latest dump is by filtering the records using a date field.
Now I have scenarios where I may need to fetch data from about 4-5 tables in the same query. In that case, which one of the below options would be better for the tables that have high number of records:

```
SELECT A.col1,
       B.col2,
       C.col3
FROM (SELECT col1, x
      FROM tableA
      WHERE posting_date = (SELECT max(posting_date) from tableA)
     ) A
JOIN
     (SELECT col2, y, z
      FROM tableB
      WHERE posting_date = (SELECT max(posting_date) from tableB)
     ) B
  ON B.y = A.x
JOIN 
    (SELECT col3, w
      FROM tableC
      WHERE posting_date = (SELECT max(posting_date) from tableC)
     ) C
  ON C.w = B.z
```

OR should I do a simple subqueries in the WHERE clause,

```
 SELECT A.col1,
        B.col2,
        C.col3
 FROM tableA A,
      tableB B,
      tableC
 WHERE A.posting_date = (SELECT max(posting_date) from tableA)
 AND B.posting_date = (SELECT max(posting_date) from tableB)
 AND C.posting_date = (SELECT max(posting_date) from tableC)
 AND A.x = B.y
 AND B.z = C.w
```

From the readability perspective, I find the second option better. But I am not too sure of the performance when there will be a lot of records in all the required tables.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Hence, the first looks much much better.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - It's nearly 12 years old, but it is still relevant and provides some pretty compelling arguments to always use the newer join syntax (I say new, but it is 29 years old, which in tech terms is not very new). I would however not expect there to be any performance difference. You could always [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) though

Comment: Hi @Neha first one is better here for handling large volume of data. every table use multiple times at both query. If it is possible try to store table wise MAX date in separate table so that you can use it when execute the main query.

Answer (score 1):

I, personally, think that using the ANSI-92 JOIN syntax and then putting the clauses in the `WHERE` would be the most readable though.

```sql
 SELECT A.col1,
        B.col2,
        C.col3
 FROM dbo.tableA A
      JOIN dbo.tableB B ON A.x = B.y
      JOIN dbo.tableC B.z = C.w
 WHERE A.posting_date = (SELECT MAX(sq.posting_date) from tableA sq)
   AND B.posting_date = (SELECT MAX(sq.posting_date) from tableB sq)
   AND C.posting_date = (SELECT MAX(sq.posting_date) from tableC sq);
```

Answer (score 0):

**I wouldn't do either of them. Window functions will serve you better.**

Obviously use proper join syntax, not those awful, deprecated comma-joins.

```sql
 SELECT A.col1,
        B.col2,
        C.col3
FROM (
    SELECT *, maxdate = MAX(a.posting_date) OVER ()
    FROM dbo.tableA a
) A
JOIN (
    SELECT *, maxdate = MAX(b.posting_date) OVER ()
    FROM dbo.tableB b
) B ON A.x = B.y
JOIN (
    SELECT *, maxdate = MAX(c.posting_date) OVER ()
    FROM dbo.tableC c
) C ON B.z = C.w
WHERE A.posting_date = A.maxdate
  AND B.posting_date = B.maxdate
  AND C.posting_date = C.maxdate;
```